# Can not bootrun due to run build.gradle file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm new to Spring world and just updated pom.xml into gradle for managing all the dependencies.

Is gradle got abandoned from the community?
Also, what's the possible root cause for this error.

Just realized Spring boot has lots of confusing error message. I really don't think this kind of error message would help any developer.
Any idea or direction for this kind of error?

The thing I only know is that I changed pom.xml into gradle and migrate the config file manually.
Thanks so much!

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z of interface org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener.

## Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'dev.15house'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:1.3.5.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE")
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.9.4'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version:'2.9.4'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.9.4'
    runtime group: 'org.webjars', name: 'angularjs', version:'1.5.7'
    runtime group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version:'3.3.7'
}
```

## Debug log

```
> Task :bootRun FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z of interface org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener.
        at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:282)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
        at dev.house.XprojApplication.main(XprojApplication.java:14)
```

Comment: You're mixing libraries that are incompatible with each other. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management: *Each release of Spring Boot is associated with a base version of the Spring Framework. We **highly** recommend that you not specify its version.* Same for basically everything else: you can't use spring boot starters with version 1.3.5.RELEASE inside an application using boot 2.1.9. Read the gradle plugin documentation.

Comment: *Is gradle got abandoned from the community?* No, not at all. But every software will not do what it should if you use it in the wrong way.

Comment: *Just realized Spring boot has lots of confusing error message. I really don't think this kind of error message would help any developer.* that's not a Spring Boot error message. It's the message of the java.lang.AbstractMethodError, thrown by the JVM because you're using classes that are incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you generating the project based on your needs from [here](https://start.spring.io).

[Here](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.1.9.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-jpa,security,web,mysql) you have the dependencies that you are needing.

This is the generated build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```